# Find method with empty string

Tags: python, string, substring

I was playing around with a function for an assignment just to better understand it. It was meant to find the last occurrence of a sub-string within a string. The function should return the position of the start of the last occurrence of the sub-string or it must return -1 if the sub-string is not found at all. The 'standard' way was as follows:

```
def find_last(full, sub):
    start = -1
    while True:
        new = full.find(sub, start + 1)
        if new == -1:
            break
        else:
            start = new
    return start
```

I wanted to try and have it search in reverse, as this seemed to be the more efficient way. So I tried this:

```
def find_last(full, sub):
    start = -1
    while True:
        new = full.find(sub, start)
        if new == -1 and abs(start) <= len(full): #evals to False when beginning of string is reached
            start -= 1
        else:
            break
    return new
```

We were given a handful of test cases which needed to be passed and my reversed function passed all but one:

```
print find_last('aaaa', 'a')
>>>3
print find_last('aaaaa', 'aa')
>>>3
print find_last('aaaa', 'b')
>>>-1
print find_last("111111111", "1")
>>>8
print find_last("222222222", "")
>>>8 #should be 9
print find_last("", "3")
>>>-1
print find_last("", "")
>>>0
```

Can someone kindly explain why find is behaving this way with negative indexing? Or is it just some glaring mistake in my code?

Comment: I know this is homework but it's good to know anyway that real code would just use .rfind() method for this.

Comment: @yak wow, that would have been much more to the point, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty string can be found at any position. Initializing `start` with `-1` makes your algorithm beginning its search at the penultimate position, not the last.

The last position is *after* the last character of the string, but you are starting to look *at* the last character of the string.

Comment: How should 'start' be properly initialized so to return the expected value of 9?

Comment: Silly question... sorry. I think: start = len(full) should do the trick then shouldn't it?

Comment: Close. `len(full)-1` is the same as `-1`.