# find() function in python2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7

`find('asdf','')` finds an empty string in `'asdf'` hence it returns `0`. 
Similarly, `find('asdf','',3)` starts to search for the string at index position `3` and hence return `3`.
Since the last index is `3`, `find('asdf','',4)` should return `-1` but it returns `4` and starts to return `-1` only if the starting index is more than or equal to `(last_index)+2`. Why is this so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find method with empty string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392054/find-method-with-empty-string)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392054/find-method-with-empty-string Actually that question shows bahaviour exactly opposite to that in my question.

Comment: The answer to that question is the answer to your question, namely: "The last position is *after* the last character of the string"

Comment: @BrenBam yes I read that but the problem is if I do `k='asdf'` and then do `k[4]` that is just after the last index of the string, I get a out of range error.

Comment: Try doing `k[4:4]`.  Since you are searching for a zero-length string, you should take a zero-length slice.

Comment: Sorry I don't get your point because I think `k[4:4]` return `''` for a very different reason. When we create a slice and don't give it any values to contain, obviously it will carry a null value. If I do k[100:900], it still gives a `''` doesn't mean there is a `''` at that index position. I'm clearly confused.

Answer (score 1):

Because `"asdf"` without its first four characters still does contain `""`. A harder check comes into play when the index *exceeds* the length of the string, but having an index equal to the string is equivalent to `"".find()`.

Comment: If I need to find out the index positions where a certain substring occurs, and I send to my user defined function, the parent string and a null string, it returns index positions one more than it should. In this case, do I need to specifically check for null string and can't really have general way of getting the correct answer with the find function?

Comment: Another question, I'm not really aware of the `''.find()` method. I'm pretty new to python. How is it that `'asdf'` without the 4 characters still has a `''` in it but after the 5th index position doesn't have a `''`? What exaclty does 'hard check' mean?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it works:

```
0 a 1 s 2 d 3 f 4
```

When you use `'asdf'.find(sub)`, it searches those five positions, labeled 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.  Those five.  Those five.  No more and no less.  It returns the first one where `'asdf'[pos:pos+len(sub)] == sub`.  If you include the `start` argument to `find`, it starts at that position.  That position.  Not one less, not one more.  If you give a start position greater than the greatest number in the list of positions, it returns -1.

In other words, the answer is what I already repeated in a comment, quoting another question answer:

**The last position [for `find`] is *after* the last character of the string**

Edit: it seems your fundamental misunderstanding relates to the notion of "positions" in a string.  `find` is not returning positions which you are expected to access as individual units.  Even if it returns 4, that doesn't mean the empty string is "at" position 4.  `find` returns *slice starts*.  You are supposed to *slice* the string starting at the given position.

So when you do `'asdf'.find('', 4)`, it starts at position 4.  It finds the empty string there because `'asdf'[4:4+len('')]==''`.  It returns 4.  That is how it works.

It is not intended that `str.find` has a one-to-one mapping between valid indexes into the actual string.  Yes, you can do tons of other indexing like `'asdf'[100:300]`.  That is not relevant for `find`.  What you know from `find` is that `'asdf'[pos:pos+len(sub)] == sub`.  You do not know that every possible index that would return `''` will be returned by `find`, nor are you guaranteed that the number returned by find is a valid index into the string if you searched for an empty string.

If you have an actual question about some *use* of this functionality, then go ahead and ask that as a separate question.  But you seem to already know how `find` works, so it's not clear what you're hoping to gain from this question.

Comment: Thanks for the details. `0 a 1 s 2 d 3 f 4` do you mean that a `''` is mapped to position 4 in this case? If so, why does str[4] give a out of range error?

Comment: @astel23: Please reread my answer.  There is nothing "at" position 4.  Find only cares about *slices*.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Even though your **bolded** part isn't inside your **Edit** block, I believe you have changed it. Your former answer said **The last position is after the last character of the string**, that was cause of my confusion. Can you explain to me what you mean by **find returns slice starts. You are supposed to slice the string starting at the given position.**