# What is the last position of a string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it true that the last position of a string in python comes after the last character of that string?
If it is true does it mean if `k='asdf'` then at index position 4 there is a `''`? If so, why doesn't k[4] return `''` instead of `out of range error`.
It has been suggested to me to try k[4:4] to see this behavior but I think the slice returns a `''` because it hasn't been given anything to contain and not specifically because of presence of a `''` at the end of every string. If I do k[300:782], I still get `''` but `find('asdf','',300)' returns -1 so this should confirm my beliefs.

Comment: @Christian In a comment in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159107/find-function-in-python2-7-5

Comment: Please see my edited answer to your other question.  You are incorrect in assuming that the "last position" for the purposes of `find` is the same thing as the "last position" for the purposes of indexing into the string.  `find` does not return positions "in" the string; it returns *starting* positions of *slices* of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not true.  The last position in `k='asdf'` is `k[3]` with is 'f'.

You are also correct that when trying to examine a slice that doesn't contain anything (`k[4:4]` or `k[300:2345]` or `k[6:5]`) python will give you an empty result.

`''` is an empty string; it is not returning a quotation mark.

@BrenBarn is absolutely right about `find`

Comment: I know already that `''` is an empty string. I just thought it's best to denote it by those combination of symbols. Yes, BrenBarn is right this time. But earlier he kept saying **' The last position is after the last character of the string '** Even someone new to python as me could tell he was wrong somewhere, that is why I asked this question and then he corrected his answers.

Comment: Now only if someone could explain to what does **find() returns starting positions of slices of the string** mean. Why does python even go into the trouble of creating a slice and checking it when it has already gone beyond the last index position.

Answer (score 1):

Kyle does a great job of answering. I will only add that you can reference the last position of a string with the index -1. so in your example k[-1] produces 'f' just as k[3] produces 'f'.